# How to add hash containing list in multipart entity?

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, multipart, multipartentity

I need my *HTTP params* should be

```
Parameters: {"MainHash"=>{"MyArray"=>[one,two,three]}}
```

For that I have tried

Try (1)

```
   for (String item : array_items) {
       entity.addPart("MainHash[MyArray[]]", new   StringBody(item));
   }
```

Result

```
Parameters: {"MainHash"=>{"MyArray"=>[nil,nil,nil]}} //nil for each item
```

Try (2)

```
entity.addPart("MainHash[MyArray[]]", new   StringBody("["+items_string+"]"));
```

Result

```
Parameters: {"MainHash"=>{"MyArray"=>"[one,two,three]"}} //quotes added to array
```

When I tried it with list with out hash it is working.

But I need to append list inside hash.

Any suggestions on the same are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want your MainHash with same key in MainArray.

So, you can try,

```
 for (String item : array_items) {
   entity.addPart("MainHash[MyArray][]", new   StringBody(item));
 }
```

It will create,

```
[one,two,three]
```

as an array.